# Sharepoint 2016 Permissions at Document Set level

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I am fairly new to SP so I would like some guidance to see if my delegated requirements are possible or not.

My scenario: Implemented so far: - I have a Doc Library made up of Doc Sets of a special Content type. - A work flow is triggered when Assigned To is changed in DS. - Home/Landing page webpart view with Assigned To DSs

To do: Permissions: - Say all Users can create new DSs in library. - However a user can only edit an already created DS if assigned to him. ( I have a field Assigned To in the Content type) - A superior Role may view/contribute any DS

So far I am thinking of 2 possible scenarios : 1) - Alter DS Permissions after Workflow is complete or 2) set an aside job to change the edit properties of each created DS according to Assigned To field and superior.

I am foreseeing that I have to remove the option to inherit permissions from parent library right?

Looking forward to some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The old way of doing this was to use an event receiver and this will still work (or webhooks in SPO).

Each time an item is modified the event receiver will trigger (ItemUpdated).

We can then intercept look at the value of assigned to, break the permissions inheritance, and then assign the permissions to include the assigned to user with the elevated rights.

If you use an event receiver then the permissions work can be done as elevated permissions if using a webhook then the webhook trigger code authenticates a a user with admin rights on the list.